# How to make the middle mouse button paste from the primary selection in tmux when mouse mode is enabled?

Tags: tmux

In most terminal emulators <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> will paste from the X Windows primary selection. In tmux with mouse mode enabled (`set -g mouse on`) <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> no longer pastes from the primary selection because the mouse click is captured by tmux rather than by the terminal emulator. To paste you have to do <kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd></kbd> to pass the click through to the terminal emulator.

How can I make <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> paste without having to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, even when mouse mode is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
# Make middle-mouse-click paste from the primary selection (without having to hold down Shift).
bind-key -n MouseDown2Pane run "tmux set-buffer -b primary_selection \"$(xsel -o)\"; tmux paste-buffer -b primary_selection; tmux delete-buffer -b primary_selection"
```

Requires `xsel` to be installed. (`sudo apt install xsel` on Ubuntu.)

#### Explanation

Adds a <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> (`MouseDown2Pane`) binding that:

1. Uses `tmux set-buffer` to load the output of the `xsel -o` command (i.e. the contents of the primary selection) into a temporary tmux paste buffer named `primary_selection`
2. Uses `tmux paste-buffer` to paste the `primary_selection` buffer into the current pane
3. Uses `tmux delete-buffer` to delete the `primary_selection` buffer. This is to avoid messing with your buffers. tmux's paste command (<kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd></kbd> by default) pastes from the most-recently-created paste buffer. We don't want the `primary_selection` buffer to become your most-recently-created buffer and replace the previous buffer for the <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd></kbd> binding. Nor do we want the `primary_selection` buffer to appear in your buffers list. So we delete it

Comment: Doesn't this only work locally?

Comment: If you prefer to use `xclip` instead of `xsel`, replace `xsel -o` by `xclip -o`, it works the same

Answer (score 2):

In [tmux 3.2](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/3.2/CHANGES#L355), this change was made.

> CHANGES FROM 3.1c TO 3.2
>
> - Add a default binding for button 2 to paste.

Comment: what does this mean? could you elaborate? it's still not working for me in tmux 3.2a

Comment: @morrow It means tmux has a binding for the _MouseDown2Pane_ event by default starting in version **3.2**.  To verify, run `tmux list-keys | grep MouseDown2`

Comment: `has a binding for the MouseDown2Pane event by default starting` Great, what does it mean? What is it binded to?

Comment: @KamilCuk A default binding means it's present by default.  (i.e. You don't have to add it yourself.)

Comment: @KamilCuk It's bound to the command shown by running `tmux list-keys MouseDown2Pane`.